# Error when doing query on RealmList<String> in realm 4.1.1

Tags: java, android, realm

I have read that new realm update supports RealmLists of String, Integer and similar objects, so I decided to change `RealmList<RealmString>` to `RealmList<String>` in one of my realm objects. `RealmString` was my realm object which contained only `String value` field. When I was doing a query to see if that list contained specific value I would write
`query.contains("nameList.value", name, Case.INSENSITIVE);`
 and it worked. After change I replaced the code with
`query.contains("nameList", name, Case.INSENSITIVE);`
however, now I'm getting following error:

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Invalid query: field 'nameList' in class 'RealmTimelineItem' is of invalid type 'STRING_LIST'.
                                                                 at io.realm.internal.fields.FieldDescriptor.verifyColumnType(FieldDescriptor.java:277)
                                                                 at io.realm.internal.fields.FieldDescriptor.setCompilationResults(FieldDescriptor.java:250)
                                                                 at io.realm.internal.fields.CachedFieldDescriptor.compileFieldDescription(CachedFieldDescriptor.java:92)
                                                                 at io.realm.internal.fields.FieldDescriptor.compileIfNecessary(FieldDescriptor.java:285)
                                                                 at io.realm.internal.fields.FieldDescriptor.getColumnIndices(FieldDescriptor.java:178)
                                                                 at io.realm.RealmQuery.contains(RealmQuery.java:1378)
```

Can queries be done on `String` realm list, or do I have to wrap it in some `RealmObject`, or is it maybe issue with my query.

Comment: Have you try ""nameList.string" ?

Comment: Unfortunatelly, still getting the same error

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> 4.0.0 (2017-10-16)
>
> RealmList can now contain String, byte[], Boolean, Long, Integer, Short, Byte, Double, Float and Date values. [**Queries**](https://github.com/realm/realm-java/issues/5361) and Importing primitive lists from JSON [**are not supported yet.**](https://github.com/realm/realm-java/issues/5361)

See the [changelog](https://github.com/realm/realm-java/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md).

Comment: Unfortunately still exists. It's only queryable if you either use the `RealmString` wrapper which will inevitably pollute your DB, or you merge them into a single String field with some separators. :/ so despite primitive list support, it's kinda... useless most of the time.

Comment: You can tell Realm that you'd want this feature by posting at https://github.com/realm/realm-object-store/issues/513

Comment: This has finally been implemented, I think they will add it in the next release on each platform (7.1.0 for Android?) (except, iOS where it's been supported since the beginning)

Comment: That is good news, iOS probably did some magic tricks because this wasn't actually supported by the Realm-Core. Will keep my eyes open for https://github.com/realm/realm-java/issues/5361#issuecomment-627774996